# Namespace 'clicker' could not be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the one error

> "the type or namespace name 'clicker' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

I know this is assembly error.  and I searched about assemly error online.
but I don' t know how to modify this code.

So my question is how to solve this error ( maybe assembly error)?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Collections;

public class ButtonExecute : MonoBehaviour {
    public float timeToSelect = 2.0f;
    private float countDown;

    private GameObject currentButton;
    private Clicker clicker = new Clicker();
```

............

```
        if (currentButton != null) {
            countDown -= Time.deltaTime;
            if (clicker.Clicked() || countDown < 0.0f){
                ExecuteEvents.Execute<IPointerClickHandler>
                (currentButton, data,
                    ExecuteEvents.pointerClickHandler);
                countDown = timeToSelect;
            }
        }
}
}
```

this is my whole code "ButtonExecute.cs".
I'm sorry for not making precise question:(

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Collections;

public class ButtonExecute : MonoBehaviour {
    public float timeToSelect = 2.0f;
    private float countDown;

    private GameObject currentButton;
    private Clicker clicker = new Clicker();

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Transform camera = Camera.main.transform;
        Ray ray = new Ray (camera.position, camera.rotation * Vector3.forward);

        RaycastHit hit;
        GameObject hitButton = null;
        PointerEventData data = new PointerEventData
        (EventSystem.current);

        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)){
            if(hit.transform.gameObject.tag == "Button"){
                hitButton = hit.transform.parent.gameObject;
            }


            if(currentButton != hitButton){
                if(currentButton != null){
                    ExecuteEvents.Execute<IPointerExitHandler>(currentButton,
                        data,ExecuteEvents.pointerExitHandler);

                }
                currentButton = hitButton;
                if(currentButton != null){
                    ExecuteEvents.Execute<IPointerEnterHandler>
                    (currentButton,data,
                        ExecuteEvents.pointerEnterHandler);
                    countDown = timeToSelect;
                }
            }

            if (currentButton != null) {
                countDown -= Time.deltaTime;
                if (clicker.Clicked() || countDown < 0.0f){
                    ExecuteEvents.Execute<IPointerClickHandler>
                    (currentButton, data,
                        ExecuteEvents.pointerClickHandler);
                    countDown = timeToSelect;
                }
            }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try RightClick on Clicker and select resolve.

Comment: You must post a [mcve], the code as shown can work in the right circumstances but it depends on the code you've hidden. Is the code in the same class as the `clicker` variable?

Comment: Is the code in a static method?

Comment: Put the whole code in your `ButtonExecute` script in your question so that people can replicate your problem.

Comment: I try right click on clicker but don't select resolve. That isn't listed:(

Comment: Is this from a tutorial or something?

Comment: Unless Clicker is included in UniteEngine, UnityEngine.EventSystems or System.Collections, you need to "import" it using the `using` statement first. If you don't know how to do it, go few steps back, learn the basics of the language and then come back to game programming.

Comment: thank you guys. 

yes. this is tutorial. I'm begginer of C# language. 

I learn about "import" about UniteEngine. And go few steps back, learn the basics of the language.

I appreciate you guys:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tutorial and I think this might help others following thee-same tutorial. You are missing the `Clicker` class. You can find this on *page 51*. Create it and put the code inside it:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Clicker
{
    public bool clicked()
    {
        return Input.anyKeyDown;
    }
}
```

and for your `if (clicker.Clicked() || countDown < 0.0f){`, from the `ButtonExecute` script, that should be `if (clicker.clicked() || countDown < 0.0f){` if you want to follow the tutorial thoroughly.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me.

That program is working!
I have been debugging this program for two days.

you are so kind. I appreciate you, great Programmer. You're GOD!

Comment: @tk08 You are welcome.  Don't forget to accept this answer.  You can do that by clicking on the checkmark next to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I have clicked the checkmark:)
I appreciate you

Comment: @tk08 No, you did not. You clicked on upvote which you can't because you don't have enough reputation to do. You should click on check mark not up or down arrow. This is how to accept answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: oh, I'm sorry for my mistake:(
I think I've clicked the checkmark. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, you did. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I appreciate you!